# how many processes nmuber should I put for 6 employee in Oracle 19c

Tags: oracle-19c

I have homework to create an Oracle database.

so there's a requirement that 6 employees are allowed to enter the database.

How many processes should I put in while creating the database for 6 employees taking into consideration that Oracle also needs some?

I supposed that every employee needs to open 10 sessions it means 10*6 =60 processes
how many should I put for the Oracle database is it enough to set 240  processes   for the Oracle  so the total should be 300 processes?

thank you.

Comment: This is not a setting that is generally used to limit the number of users: the trick is to make sure you can support the minimum number of processes required for your application. Start with the default and tune the number of processes based on observed behavior of the system. If you must limit concurrent users or sessions, use user profiles.

Comment: @pmdba thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have homework ...

Thanks for being honest.

> there's a requirement that 6 employees are allowed to enter the database.

So each one will need:

- An account, with a password (I'm guessing you're not up to the "fancier" flavours of "IDENTIFIED BY" yet).
  Personally, if we're talking *Application Development* here, I'd have the Application use its own, dedicated, account and *not* put individual *User* accounts into the database itself.  It's just too much hassle (e.g. how *does* a User reset their database password when they can't get into the database ...   because they need to reset their database password?).
- A Default Tablespace (usually USERS).
  This is somewhere for them to create their own tables.
- A *Quota* in that Default Tablespace.
  This is how *much data* they're allowed to keep in there.  (Without this, you *can* create your own table but then you can't put anything *into* it!)
- The System Privilege that allows them to Create a Session (hint!) in the database, a.k.a. "Log in".

> ... every employee needs to open 10 sessions ...

That's best controlled through a PROFILE parameter that limits the number Sessions Per User (hint!).
**DO NOT change the DEFAULT Profile**.
That's the default for *every* database account, including all the internal, System ones and they probably *do* need more than 10 sessions each!

Instead, create a *new* profile called, say, "USERS" alter the settings on *that* profile *and then* make your new User account use that Profile.

If you're going to have yet more accounts that hold your company's "real" data tables (and you *should*), then you'll also need some Roles that convey privileges on *those* schema objects and grant those to your User accounts as well.

> How many processes should I put in ...

Firstly, don't worry too much about Processes.
Think of them as things that Oracle Database will start up, all by itself, as and when it needs them.  On a sensibly-sized machine, you won't need to worry about these unless you start hitting many *thousands* of users.

Secondly, for only six users, you probably *shouldn't* change anything from the defaults.
A plain vanilla database will be running something like **fifty** internal processes, right out of the box; more if you add in any of the Oracle "optional extras", like DataGuard.  Your database will *barely notice* six users - until they start doing stupid things, of course.  :-)